# Visual Studio 2022 automatic deactivation of debug mode after 2 minutes of inactivity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I installed VS 2022, but I noticed that if I stop at breakpoint and do nothing for about 2 minutes, debug mode stops by itself, can it be changed somehow?

I updated VS from 17.1.6 to 17.2.3 and at this point VS dies after clicking start ...

Comment: What do you mean by "stops by itself"? It automatically continues execution? It crashes?

Comment: I'am waiting in breakpoint and after 2min it turns off as if I clicked Stop debugging. But after updating, when I click start, VS dies. It is impossible to click anything, I can only see the loading cursor icon

Comment: No Idea what this could be, it's definitely not normal. Try a full reinstall of VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing CodeMain and PostSharp from extensions (only the two I had installed) helped.